# Set value from an array of object to another array of object using mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the document as mentioned below.
Set value field of first object from valueArray as the last value from the comments array using mongodb updateOne query

```json
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    user: "abc",
    status: false,
    valueArray: [
      {
        value: 15,
        isValid: true
      },
      {
        value: 75,
        isValid: false
      },
      {
        value: 12,
        isValid: false
      }
    ],
    comments: [
      {
        value: "hello"
      },
      {
        value: "world"
      },
      {
        value: "from"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Want to set the value field of first object from valueArray as the last value from the comments array using mongodb updateOne query

If the comments array is empty set the value as empty string

Query I am trying is :

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1
},
{
  "$set": {
    "valueArray.0.value": {
      $arrayElemAt: [
        "$comments.value",
        -1
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Expected Output

```json
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "comments": [
      {
        "value": "hello"
      },
      {
        "value": "world"
      },
      {
        "value": "from"
      }
    ],
    "status": false,
    "user": "abc",
    "valueArray": [
      {
        "isValid": true,
        "value": "from"
      },
      {
        "isValid": false,
        "value": 75
      },
      {
        "isValid": false,
        "value": 12
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$reduce` to iterate through the array and append elements to the accumulator according to your criteria.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "valueArray": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$valueArray",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              // first element, so accumulator is still []
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  [],
                  "$$value"
                ]
              },
              "then": [
                // perform your logic
                {
                  value: {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$comments.value",
                      -1
                    ]
                  },
                  isValid: "$$this.isValid"
                }
              ],
              "else": {
                // simply append to accumulator for remaining array entries
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JBMuQ3nsqgz)